# Null pointer exception using an external file

Tags: java, mysql, file, path, nullpointerexception

I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to execute a script file using another file to find the script.

Here is the code used to execute the connection to MySql DB using the file DB.conf. If the DB doesn't exists, using the DB.conf file, the code should extract the path of the script (the path of the script is the same of the DB.conf).

Here is my code :

```
public class MySqlConnection {

/**
 * campo per la connessione al database
 */
protected Connection connessione;

/**
 * campo statement
 */
protected Statement stat;

/**
 * campo per i risultati della query
 */
  protected ResultSet res;

    /**
 * campo di preparazione statement
 */
   protected PreparedStatement prepStat;

   protected boolean connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException,
        IOException {
    connessione = null;
    boolean connection = false;


    InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/DB.conf");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    new Driver();
    String src = br.readLine().toString();
    String db = br.readLine().toString();
    String user = br.readLine().toString();
    String password = br.readLine().toString();

    try {
        String jdbc = (new StringBuilder("jdbc:mysql://")).append(src)
                .append("/").append(db).toString();
        connessione = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc, user, password);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if (e.getErrorCode() == 1049) {
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Database 'Carloan' non esistente! \nInstallazione del db in corso...");
            String jdbc = (new StringBuilder("jdbc:mysql://")).append(src)
                    .toString();
            connessione = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc, user, password);
            //HERE I EXTRACT THE PATH OF THE SCRIPT FROM THE FILE DB.CONF
            //AND THAN I GET THE NULLPOINTER
            String sqlScriptPath = br.readLine().toString();
            InputStream input2 = getClass().getResourceAsStream(sqlScriptPath);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input2));
            ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(connessione, false, false);
            sr.runScript(reader);

            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(null, "Installazione completata!");
        } else {
            if (e.getErrorCode() == 1045) {
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(
                                null,
                                "Username o password del DB errati! \n Controllare il file di configurazione e riprovare.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(
                                null,
                                "Errore nella connessione al database! \n       Contattare l'amministratore di sistema.\nIl sistema verrà chiuso ora.");
            }
        }
    }
    br.close();
    input.close();
    connection = true;
    return connection;
  }

 protected boolean close() throws SQLException {
    boolean chiuso = false;
    connessione.close();
    chiuso = true;
    return chiuso;
}

}
```

This is the content of the DB.conf file

```
localhost:3306
CarLoan
root
root
CarLoan.sql
```

This is the stackTrace of the nullPointer:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at integration_tier.OggettiDAO.MySqlConnection.connect(MySqlConnection.java:70)
at integration_tier.OggettiDAO.CategoriaDAO.create(CategoriaDAO.java:28)
at business_tier.ApplicationService.add(ApplicationService.java:21)
at presentation_tier.ApplicationController.handleRequest(ApplicationController.java:41)
at presentation_tier.FrontController.handleRequest(FrontController.java:29)
at presentation_tier.GuiController.ControllerSchermataImpiegato.catdao(ControllerSchermataImpiegato.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: According to your stack trace, you have an exception at line 70 of MySqlConnection.java.  Since we cannot see line numbers, what is the code at line 70 ?

Comment: The code is:  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input2)); @JoshDM

Answer (score 0):

According to your stack trace, you have an exception at line 70 of `MySqlConnection.java`. According to you, this line is

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input2));
```

The call to `getClass().getResourceAsStream(sqlScriptPath);` is returning a `null` value, setting `InputStream input2` to `null`.  You cannot create `new InputStreamReader(input2)` with a `null` variable `input2`.

According to your file `DB.conf`, the value of `sqlScriptPath` is `"CarLoan.sql"`.  Considering your call to `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/DB.conf");` is successful, perhaps the value of `sqlScriptPath` in `DB.conf` should be `"/CarLoan.sql"`.

Confirm the value of `sqlScriptPath` is set to `"/CarLoan.sql"`, and is being retrieved as not null from `getClass().getResourceAsStream(sqlScriptPath);`

Confirm the file, explicitly named `"CarLoan.sql"` with the same capitalization, is in the same folder as `"DB.conf"` and has the same security access permissions as the `"DB.conf"` file.

Also, make sure all your IO `.close()` calls are done in a `finally` clause.

Comment: Yes, I modified the value of sqlScriptPath with `"/CarLoan.sql"` but it gaves me the NullPointerException. And yes, `getClass().getResourceAsStream(sqlScriptPath);` return null

Comment: Does `CarLoan.sql` exist?  Is it in the same folder as `DB.conf`?

Comment: Yes, the files are in the same folder

Comment: Were they in the same folder from the start, or did you just put them together?  If you just put them together, you will need to recycle the container and try again.

Comment: Does it have the same capitalization?  Are the permissions on CarLoan.sql the same as the permissions on DB.conf ?

Comment: There was a problem with the path because in the executable jar folders weren't createad